# tizen wearable invisible/background app (adding gestures)

Tags: background, gesture, tizen, sony-smartwatch

I am wondering if it is possible to add some gestured to tizen wearable to make it possible to activate the screen using a specific gesture.

i already found some tutorials for the javascript code of the gestured (such as double tap). but what i want is following:

either just add the gesture to the os making it possible to choose the activation gesture in the settings menu (i think this will not be possible?) or make an app that only runs in the background (like a service in android, i know tizen cant have services but maybe it is possible somehow to run an app in the backround somehow). That app also should work when the screen is turned off, so i can activate it with the gesture.

i already saw the config line "backround-support=enable". will this help somehow? does the app also run while the screen is turned off then? if yes --> how to turn the screen on then

sorry for those million questions. i hope someone can help me :)

thanks for all your effords

EDIT:
ok, i got a problem implementing this. I set the property in my config.xml but whenever i re-open (in task mgr) the app, it starts from new. Also it does not detect my gesture while the screen is turned off.
here is my code: (i am using the [hammer](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js) api to detect a double tap)
config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/DoubleTap" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <tizen:application id="3orhQYRmuI.DoubleTap" package="3orhQYRmuI" required_version="2.2"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>DoubleTap</name>
    <tizen:setting background-support="enable" />
</widget>
```

main.js:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
        if(e.keyName == "back")
            tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
    });

    var element = document.getElementById('content');
    var mc = new Hammer.Manager(element, {tapHighlightColor: "green" , showTouches: true});

    // Tap recognizer with minimal 2 taps
    mc.add( new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 }) );

    mc.get('doubletap').recognizeWith('singletap');

    mc.on("doubletap", function(ev) {
        //$('#textbox').html("gay");
        element.textContent += ev.type +" ";
        var isScreenOn = tizen.power.isScreenOn();
        if(!isScreenOn) {
            tizen.power.turnScreenOn();
        }
    });
});
```

and index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="A single-page template generated by Tizen Wearable Web IDE"/>

    <title>Tizen Wearable Web IDE - Tizen Wearable - jQuery</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class=contents id="content">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the double tap recognition works perfectly and writes doubletap on the app screen. when i re-open the app the whole screen is empty again and starts to write new doubletap's. so its not really running in the background :/
also, it does not recognize my doubletaps when the app is in the background. neither when the app is in the foreground and the screen is turned off.
do i need to use hide() first somehow or did i do a mistake in the code?

Comment: Have you tried any code on your device? SO is rather a place to help fixing programming problems ;) 

Also are you talking about Tizen based wearables or Sony smartwatches, I'm asking because those are two different products

Comment: first, thanks for your answer :) i am talking about a tizen wearable watch, the samsung gear S. until now i didnt try any code on my device. it was more a general question if it is possible to make such an app or not. tizen has many destrictions and normally i am programming on android devices so its a new topic to me. thats why i wanted to ask for the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your web app to run in background by setting `background-support=enable` property in config.xml file. When you set it, your app will be run even the screen is turned off and will be able to listen for devicemotion event, which helps you to recognize gestures.

To set screen on you can use method from [tizen power API](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/power.html). 
To control applications (to launch or hide) you shoud use [Application API](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.device.apireference/tizen/application.html).

You can't add your custom gestures to OS setting menu and you user should remember to launch you app back after each reboot.

EDIT:
You can't wake up your screen using touch gestures when app is hidden, because you don't have access to element that you are currently touch. When your app is in background, your document is not visible (other app is focused and covers yours).

But you can activate your screen using **motion** gesture, f.e. listening a devicemotion events.

```
function motionListener (e) {
    var acc = e.acceleration,
        x = Math.abs(Math.round(acc.x)),
        y = Math.abs(Math.round(acc.y)),
        z = Math.abs(Math.round(acc.z)),
        diff;

    if (x >= 5 || y >= 5 || z >= 5) {
        console.log("Shake!");
        tizen.power.turnScreenOn();
    }
}

window.addEventListener("devicemotion", motionListener, true);
```

Comment: thank you very much :) those information were exactly what i wanted :) thank you for your help.

Comment: well, i need your help again. i posted the code in my first post and all my problems. it does not really recognize my gesture while the app is in the background or even while the screen is turned off. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can't receive touch events from an element which is not displayed, this happens when app is put to background.
However, when app is in background (hidden) any DOM changes doesn't work. You need to refresh your layout when app is bringed to front (focus event). 
To check if you receive events print something to console using console.log method

Comment: i am worried i cant follow you. how do you mean i need to refresh my layout? how is it done? so actually i cant activate my screen when the app is in the background?

Comment: Sorry for my misteake with DOM manipulation. Of course you can manipulate your DOM and don't need to refresh your layout. I had some DOM manipulation done in requestAnimationFrame callback, which won't work when app is in background or screen is off. This makes me wrong.

Comment: thank you for your answer and your code. thats sad :( activating with motions there are many false positives and also false negatives :( so there isnt a way to do an eventlistener for touch gestures? :/

Comment: I've just played with Gear S and event monitor. I've found second obstacle. If you turn off the screen (f.e. using `tizen.power.turnScreenOff()`) you will not be able to receive touch events even if your app is not in background.

Comment: yeah i also experienced this but i didnt had an event monitor. isnt there a way to do somehow same like with the motion gesture listerner? i mean that you do not register the touch event on a div container in the app display, but on the window (screen) which would maybe be somehow like `window.addEventListener("doubletap", touchListener, true);` with a function touchListener which detects the touch event. sadly i am absolutely beginner in tizen app programming so i do not know exactly how to do the correct syntax, but maybe it is possible on a way like this?

Comment: you can add touch listener to window but it doesn't work when app is in background. You can play with event monitor too. Debug your app using Tizen SDK and in console call `monitorEvents(window,"touch")`. More info about monitor event you will find in [Dev Tools Command Line API Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#monitoreventsobject-events)

Comment: ahh ok :( tizen wearable is slightly disappointing in these things :/